# Internet Explorer: Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, undefined, undefined-reference

I have a javascript calculator that works without errors in every browser except Internet Explorer. I need to know why Internet Explorer is giving me this error at Line 14: "Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference."

Here is the calculator code:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
<script>

function showpay() {
"use strict";
if ((document.loanCalc.loan.value === null || document.loanCalc.loan.value.length === 0) ||
        (document.loanCalc.months.value === null || document.loanCalc.months.value.length === 0)
        ||
        (document.loanCalc.rate.value === null || document.loanCalc.rate.value.length === 0)) { document.loanCalc.pay.value = " ";
    } else {
     var princ = document.loanCalc.loan.value;
     var term  = document.loanCalc.months.value;
     var intr   = document.loanCalc.rate.value / 1200;
     document.loanCalc.pay.value = Math.round(princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intr), term))));
}
// payment = principle * monthly interest/(1 - (1/(1+MonthlyInterest)*Months))
}

</script>


<form name=loanCalc method=POST>
<table class="calculator">

<tr><td>Loan Amount</td><td align=right><input type=number onInput='showpay()' name=loan size=10 value="15000"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Term in Months</td><td align=right><input type=number onInput='showpay()' name=months size=10 value="60"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Interest Rate</td><td align=right><input type=number onInput='showpay()' name=rate size=10 value="1.99"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Monthly Payment</td></tr>

<tr><td align=left class=result><span>$</span><output name=pay>263</output></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Internet Explorer's debugger says, "Unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference" at Line 14: `document.loanCalc.pay.value = Math.round(princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intr), term))));`

The code works in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox without errors. You can see the calculator in action on this page: http://bloomcu.com/test-page/

Why am I getting this error in Internet Explorer?

Comment: You can see the calculator in action on this page: http://bloomcu.com/test-page/

Comment: It's because your HTML is all over the place.  Missing or inconsistent quotes.  No id's for your field items.  td align=right which is deprecated and unusable anyway...

Comment: snarky answer: "Internet Explorer" - you answered your own question.

Comment: IE doesn't support html5 <output> tag, that is why document.loanCalc.pay is undefined

Comment: @Z.Z. Interesting. What can I use instead of <output>?

Comment: @Z.Z. I replaced <output> with <input> and that worked. You can see my answer for the full solution. Thanks for your help! Who knows how long it would have taken me to figure out that IE doesn't support <output>.

Answer (score 0):

This is one line corrected (as per my comment)

```
<tr><td>Loan Amount </td><td><input type="number" onInput="showpay()" name="loan" id="loan" size="10" value="15000" style="text-align:right"></td></tr>
```

If you fix them all like this, it will be more in the direction of working everywhere.

Comment: Thanks. I made those changes, but it's still not working in Explorer. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this on IE if it works

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
<script>
document.loanCalc.pay = document.getElementById("pay");

function showpay() {
    "use strict";
    if ((document.loanCalc.loan.value === null || document.loanCalc.loan.value.length === 0) ||
        (document.loanCalc.months.value === null || document.loanCalc.months.value.length === 0)
        ||
        (document.loanCalc.rate.value === null || document.loanCalc.rate.value.length === 0)) { document.loanCalc.pay.innerHTML = " ";
    } else {
     var princ = document.loanCalc.loan.value;
     var term  = document.loanCalc.months.value;
     var intr   = document.loanCalc.rate.value / 1200;
     document.loanCalc.pay.innerHTML = Math.round(princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intr), term))));
}
// payment = principle * monthly interest/(1 - (1/(1+MonthlyInterest)*Months))
}

</script>


<form name=loanCalc method=POST>
<table class="calculator">

<tr><td>Loan Amount</td><td align=right><input type=number onInput='showpay()' name=loan size=10 value="15000"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Term in Months</td><td align=right><input type=number onInput='showpay()' name=months size=10 value="60"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Interest Rate</td><td align=right><input type=number onInput='showpay()' name=rate size=10 value="1.99"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Monthly Payment</td></tr>

<tr><td align=left class=result><span>$</span><span id='pay'>263</span></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Z.Z. was correct: Explorer does not support the `<output>` tag. Therefore, I replaced `<output>` with `<input>` and then used `disabled="disabled"` to prevent users from changing the result of the calculation.

The final code looks like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=10">
<script>

function showpay() {
"use strict";

if ((document.loanCalc.loan.value === null || document.loanCalc.loan.value.length === 0) ||
        (document.loanCalc.months.value === null || document.loanCalc.months.value.length === 0) ||
        (document.loanCalc.rate.value === null || document.loanCalc.rate.value.length === 0)) 
    { document.loanCalc.pay.value = " ";
} 

else {
     var princ = document.loanCalc.loan.value;
     var term  = document.loanCalc.months.value;
     var intr   = document.loanCalc.rate.value / 1200;
     document.loanCalc.pay.value = Math.round(princ * intr / (1 - (Math.pow(1 / (1 + intr), term))));
}
// payment = principle * monthly interest/(1 - (1/(1+MonthlyInterest)*Months))
}

</script>

<form name=loanCalc method=POST>
<table class="calculator">

<tr><td>Loan Amount</td><td><input type="number" onInput="showpay()" name="loan" id="loan" size="10" value="15000"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Term in Months</td><td><input type="number" onInput="showpay()" name="months" id="months" size="10" value="60"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Interest Rate</td><td><input type="number" onInput="showpay()" name="rate" id="rate" size="10" value="1.99"></td></tr>

<tr><td>Monthly Payment</td></tr>

<tr><td class=result><span>$</span><input name="pay" id="pay" value="263" disabled="disabled"></input></td></tr>

</table>
</form>
```

Thank you all for your help.